# How to diagnose a MacBook Pro (2019) CPU spiking periodically?

Tags: cpu, performance, macbook

My wife has a MacBook Pro (MacBookPro15,1) an it is running macOS Sonoma (14.3). She got it in 2019. It has an Intel i9 2.3GHz CPU and a Radeon Pro 560X and 16GB of RAM. She doesn't do a whole lot with it.

One thing she does do is play a Roblox game with our kids (our kids play on iPads and sometimes a Windows computer). She says the game often gets laggy. She has noticed that the CPU spikes in Activity Monitor when the lag happens.

But a single Roblox game spiking an i9 processor doesn't seem right to me. She doesn't have any other programs running and the spikes come and go in irregular waves. We've tried reboots also. What could I try or look into more deeply on a Mac to investigate the cause?

Comment: “My wife has a MacBook Pro. She got it in 2019. It has an i9 2.3GHz version Radeon Pro 560X and 16GB of RAM.” What is the exact model and what version of macOS is the MacBook Pro running? That is more important. Also, you should check CPU activuty in “Activity Monitor” which is located in “/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor” and see if that reveals anything.

Comment: Could be overheating and the CPU thermal throttling... open it up and clean out the fans and potentially change thermal compounds.

Comment: It is running Sonoma 14.3. I didn't know there were exact models of MacBook Pros. I thought the year and CPU was all there was to it. In system Information, it says MacBookPro15,1. Is that what you want? We do check Activity Monitor and the only thing running is the game.

The laptop does not feel like it is over heating.